# TCP - Why do RST packets not require acknowledgements (and FIN packets do)?

Tags: tcp

From what I can tell, RST packets do not require acknowledgments.

My question is, what happens if a RST packet doesn't reach the other participant? How can the other participant tell something has gone wrong? Will they just retransmit the original packet that has caused the RST, and then they will hopefully receive the RST?

This reminds me of a similar situation - say the other participant has already sent a FIN packet and I have already acknowledged it. Now I want to send a FIN packet. Why should the FIN in this case be acknowledged, but not the RST in the first case? In both cases the sender of the RST/FIN is completely through with a connection (although in the case of a RST it may have never existed in the first place).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

FIN tells the receiver of the FIN that the sender of the FIN is done sending data, but it will still listen. The receiver of a FIN is under no obligation to stop, unless it is also done, and it can keep sending data to the sender of the FIN until it is also done, whereupon it sends a FIN. It is all very courteous and orderly with ACKs to let the FIN sender know that the FIN receiver has seen the FIN, else the FIN sender will need to resend the FIN in case it got lost.

On the other hand, a RST is sent when a TCP receives something unexpected or for which it has no connection. TCP cannot send an ACK if there is no connection because there is no data to ACK if there is no connection. Courtesy and orderliness are non-existent for a RST because the sender of the RST is not interested in hearing from the sender of the segment that caused the RST, so an ACK from the receiver of a RST would again generate a RST.

> As a general rule, reset (RST) must be sent whenever a segment arrives
> which apparently is not intended for the current connection. A reset
> must not be sent if it is not clear that this is the case.

When a RST is generated, the segment causing the RST is dropped because there is no destination process for reception of the segment data.

> There are three groups of states:
>
> 1. If the connection does not exist (CLOSED) then a reset is sent in
>    response to any incoming segment except another reset. In
>    particular, SYNs addressed to a non-existent connection are rejected
>    by this means.
>
>    If the incoming segment has an ACK field, the reset takes its
>    sequence number from the ACK field of the segment, otherwise the
>    reset has sequence number zero and the ACK field is set to the sum
>    of the sequence number and segment length of the incoming segment.
>    The connection remains in the CLOSED state.
> 2. If the connection is in any non-synchronized state (LISTEN,
>    SYN-SENT, SYN-RECEIVED), and the incoming segment acknowledges
>    something not yet sent (the segment carries an unacceptable ACK), or
>    if an incoming segment has a security level or compartment which
>    does not exactly match the level and compartment requested for the
>    connection, a reset is sent.
>
>    If our SYN has not been acknowledged and the precedence level of the
>    incoming segment is higher than the precedence level requested then
>    either raise the local precedence level (if allowed by the user and
>    the system) or send a reset; or if the precedence level of the
>    incoming segment is lower than the precedence level requested then
>    continue as if the precedence matched exactly (if the remote TCP
>    cannot raise the precedence level to match ours this will be
>    detected in the next segment it sends, and the connection will be
>    terminated then).  If our SYN has been acknowledged (perhaps in this
>    incoming segment) the precedence level of the incoming segment must
>    match the local precedence level exactly, if it does not a reset
>    must be sent.
>
>    If the incoming segment has an ACK field, the reset takes its
>    sequence number from the ACK field of the segment, otherwise the
>    reset has sequence number zero and the ACK field is set to the sum
>    of the sequence number and segment length of the incoming segment.
>    The connection remains in the same state.
> 3. If the connection is in a synchronized state (ESTABLISHED,
>    FIN-WAIT-1, FIN-WAIT-2, CLOSE-WAIT, CLOSING, LAST-ACK, TIME-WAIT),
>    any unacceptable segment (out of window sequence number or
>    unacceptible acknowledgment number) must elicit only an empty
>    acknowledgment segment containing the current send-sequence number
>    and an acknowledgment indicating the next sequence number expected
>    to be received, and the connection remains in the same state.
>
>    If an incoming segment has a security level, or compartment, or
>    precedence which does not exactly match the level, and compartment,
>    and precedence requested for the connection, a reset is sent and
>    connection goes to the CLOSED state.  The reset takes its sequence
>    number from the ACK field of the incoming segment.

Comment: In other words: You don't ACK a RST, because the RST is already playing the role of an ACK in the first place (i.e. it's sent in response to something else). If ACK means "I received your segment as expected," RST means "I received your segment, but, uh, why did you send me this?"

Answer (score 5):

RST is a "mission abort" - waiting for an ACK (that's not unlikely to never come) isn't productive.

In contrast, FIN is a completely normal message in the connection lifecycle, so it's ACKed.